# Perform True/False operation on a column based on the condition present in another column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame([[1,"A",32,">30"],[2,"B",12,"<10"],[3,"C",45,">=45"]],columns=['id', 'input', 'val', 'cond'])
```

I want to perform an operation on column "val" based on the condition present in "cond" column and get the True/False result in "Output" column.

Expected Output:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([[1,"A",32,">30",True],[2,"B",12,"<10",False],[3,"C",45,">=45",True]],columns=['id', 'input', 'val', 'cond',"Output"])
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
df_in['output']=pd.eval(df_in['val'].astype(str)+df_in['cond'])
```

**OR**

If needed performance use the below method but also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) but I think in your case it is safe to use `eval`:

```
df_in['output']=list(map(lambda x:eval(x),(df_in['val'].astype(str)+df_in['cond']).tolist()))
```

**OR**

Even more efficient and fastest:

```
from numpy.core import defchararray

df_in['output']=list(map(lambda x:eval(x),defchararray.add(df_in['val'].values.astype(str),df_in['cond'].values)))
```

output of `df_in`:

```
    id  input   val     cond    output
0   1   A       32      >30     True
1   2   B       12      <10     False
2   3   C       45      >=45    True
```

**Time Comparison:** `using %%timeit -n 1000`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `numexpr`

```
import numexpr
df_in['output'] = df_in.apply(lambda x: numexpr.evaluate(f"{x['val']}{x['cond']}"), axis=1 )
```

---

```
   id  input   val     cond    output
0   1   A       32      >30     True
1   2   B       12      <10     False
2   3   C       45      >=45    True
```

**Time Comparison:**
using `%%timeit -n 1000`

using `apply` and `numexpr`:

```
865 µs ± 140 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

using `pd.eval`:

```
2.5 ms ± 363 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```